# Python: function as argument

Tags: python, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm diving into the concept of passing functions as arguments to other functions. I have a question related to this:
when you pass a function as argument: can you also set a fixed value for some of the parameters(apart from their default value)?, something like this:

```py
def my_cross(y,cross=2):
    y=y*cross;
    return y;

def my_print(func,x):
    print(func(x))

my_print(my_cross(cross=3),3)
```

won't execute because some arguments have not been given to my_cross.

Tried also giving a default value to the first argument:

```py
def my_cross(y: int = 1,cross=2):
    y=y*cross;
    return y;

def my_print(func,x):
    print(func(x))

my_print(my_cross(cross=3),3)
```

but resulted in:
`TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: I'm not fully sure I understand, but it sounds like you want `functools.partial`.

Comment: You use `func` with 1 argument in definition of `my_print`. So you can define only `y` argument. E. g. `my_print(my_cross, 3)` prints `6`.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake in your `my_print(my_cross(cross=3),3)` line

`my_cross(cross=3)` already called and returned an `int` object, and `my_print` tries to call an int object, which is not callable.

For your situation, you can do this:

```py
def my_print(func, **kwargs):
    print(func(**kwargs))

my_print(my_cross, cross=3)
```

In this case, you put a `callable` object `my_cross` and `cross=3` as kwargs, and function will implement this as `print(func(cross=3))`

Comment: Oh, that's true. Is there no way to pass the function with one fixed argument and the other without any default value? (the idea of the first code version)

Comment: `my_print(my_cross, y='your val' cross=3)`, and if you don't wand cross, just don't push this arg, this will use `cross=2` in function as default value

Comment: @NelttjeN Your code will to the error: `TypeError: my_print() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y'`

Comment: @YuriGinsburg i tried it myself with `my_print(my_cross, y=3)` and it works fine. `y` expected as `kwargs`, and puts to `my_cross`

Comment: @NelttjeN This is different from your previous comment. You cannot pass two arguments to `my_cross`.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg why? `y` and `cross` expected in `my_cross` and puts as `**kwargs` into it. I also just tried `my_print(my_cross, y=3, cross=3)`, still works fine

Comment: @NelttjeN Sorry, I called OP's `my_cross`, not yours.